# html5 offline searcher - is it possible?

Tags: xml, html, local-storage

I ran into a problem with **html5 local storage** with my offline searcher, which is meant
to run from USB drive or CD.

I have an XML file, size of 66 MB and I'm importing it to local storage where I could
do some queries for searching. But problem is, that first time I (or any user) visit page is taking around **6 minutes** to import everything from xml. Is there any other way to reduce time or some other way to create db to search offline?

Thanks in advanced, J

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON instead; that should reduce filesize and parse time.

However, it will still be slow.
You really need to use a database.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support you might be able to use sqlite instead of local storage. If you did that, you could probably send the user a sqlite file directly, which would at least eliminate the need to import the file.

The suggestion to use json instead of xml is a good one. You also might consider breaking the data up into a few asynchronous requests, so the db can be populated in a few batches while the user is doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

you can try workers to fill the localstorage.

see [this example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/exp_webstorage.html). they load map-tiles into the local storage. maybe similar size as your xml-file.